# Отличия переопределения метода от перекрытия

Tags: c#, классы, функции, виртуальная-функция

Чем отличается перекрытие от переопределения метода?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Перекрытие (в ваших терминах) означает, что метод в производном классе скрывает метод с той же самой сигнатурой в базовом классе.

Поэтому в C# рекомендуется для методов производных классов, которые перекрывают методы базовых классов, использовать ключевое слово `new`. Если вы забудете это сделать, то компилятор вас предупредит, что вы скрываете одноименную функцию с той же сигнатурой в базовом классе.

Например,

```
class Base
{
    public void Hello() { Console.WriteLine( "I'm the base class" ); }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public new void Hello() { Console.WriteLine( "I'm the derived class" ); }
}
```

В этом случае для ссылок  на базовый класс `Base` всегда будет вызываться метод `Hello` базового класса, а для ссылок на производный класс будет вызываться метод `Hello` производного класса.

Например,

```
Base b = new Base();
b.Hello(); // I'm the base class

Derived d = new Derived();
d.Hello(); // I'm the derived class

b = d;
b.Hello(); // I'm the base class
```

Переопределение применяется к виртуальным функциям. В производном классе виртуальная функция переопределяется. Для этого в базовом классе функция должна быть определена с ключевым словом `virtual` (или `abstract`), а в производном классе для ее переопределения необходимо указывать другое ключевое слово `override`.

Например,

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Hello() { Console.WriteLine( "I'm the base class" ); }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Hello() { Console.WriteLine( "I'm the derived class" ); }
}
```

Различие с предыдущим примером состоит в том, что если ссылка базового класса указывает на объект производного класса, то в этом случае будет вызвана переопределенная функция производного класса.

```
Base b = new Base();
b.Hello(); // I'm the base class

Derived d = new Derived();
d.Hello(); // I'm the derived class

b = d;
b.Hello(); `// I'm the derived class`
```

То есть различие состоит в этих двух предложениях. В первом случае для перекрытия

```
b = d;
b.Hello(); // I'm the base class
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

а во втором случае при переопределении имеем

```
b = d;
b.Hello(); `// I'm the derived class`
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

То есть в первом случае мы в каждом новом производном классе в иерархии классов объявляем новую функцию, которая скрывает функцию с той же сигнатурой в базовых классах. А во втором случае функция с тем же именем заново не объявляется, а переопределяется уже объявленная функция базового класса.

Это позволяет динамически вызывать нужное определение одной и той же функции в зависимости от объекта, с которым функция вызывается.

Answer (score 4):

Переопределение виртуального метода базового класса — это создание метода в порождённом классе, имеющим точно такую же сигнатуру (и отмеченным специальным ключевым словом). При этом для связки виртуальный метод + его переопределение действует позднее связывание: вызов метода по ссылке на базовый класс может привести к вызову перегруженного метода.

Переопределений невиртуальных методов не бывает.

Перекрытие метода — это просто определение в классе или производном от него метода с таким же именем (и возможно отличающейся сигнатурой). При этом который из двух методов будет вызван, известно во время компиляции.

Comment: Перекрытие в вопросе, я так понимаю, - это `name shadowing`, а не перегрузка (`overriding`). С `C#` не знаком, но по-моему определить в классе два метода с одним и тем же именем и сигнатурой нельзя.

Comment: @PavelParshin, в наследниках можно

Comment: @Grundy без `override` нельзя?

Comment: @Grundy, к наследникам вопросов нет. Я это к тому, что из фразы "Перекрытие метода — это просто определение в классе или производном от него метода с таким же именем (и возможно отличающейся сигнатурой)" следует, что я могу определить два одинаковых метода в одном классе.

Comment: @Suvitruf, не понял вопроса: в наследнике можно создать метод с той же сигнатурой, что и в базовом, без указания ключевого слова `override`

Comment: @PavelParshin, да, с одним именем и сигнатурой, два метода в классе быть не могут, что в принципе логично :) Но в ответе больше внимание на _одно имя_.

Comment: @PavelParshin: Угу, если в одном классе, то сигнатуры обязаны быть разными. А если в разных, то могут и совпадать. (При этом компилятор выдаст предупреждение, если нету ключевого слова `new`.)